# Target specific character within value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following input text field (via a Mailchimp signup form):

```
<input type="text" value="First name*" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME"/>
```

1. Is it possible to make the value two different colours? I want to make the value of value attribute of the input tag that contains "First name" with black and the "*" with red.
2. Is there a way to do this without losing the Mailchimp form functionality that it preserves?

Comment: No, you should consider a hacky solution.

Comment: I don't think so.  You could use a background image with a red asterisk to denote it's required if you wanted.  Apply it to any `input.required` elements.

Comment: @CaffGeek That idea is winning so far, not ideal but maybe the only way out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with the following:

```
.required {
    background-image: url('images/rwcmd-asterisk.png')!IMPORTANT;
    background-repeat:no-repeat!IMPORTANT;
    background-position:97% 16%;
    }
```

Wasn't ideal but had no other choice really.

Comment: There's not much else you can do.

Comment: what happens when the user edits the value - how is the asterisk positioned in relation to the new text, or do you simply remove the image?

Comment: @nobody I thought the same so I positioned it far right in the top corner so it doesn't interfere with the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the content to something like this:

```
<p class="required">
    <input type="text" value="First name" name="FNAME"
        class="required" id="mce-FNAME" />
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.required:after {
    color:red;
    content:"*";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uAKEa/